# Performance with Web API

Tags: c#, .net, performance, asp.net-web-api

I'm with some performance problems working with WEB Api. On my real/production code, I'll do a SOAP WS call, on this sample, I'll just sleep. I have 400+ clients sending request's to the Web API.

I guess it's a problem with web api, because if I open 5 process, I can handle more requests than when I'm only with one process.

My test async version of the controller looks like this

```
[HttpPost]
public Task<HttpResponseMessage> SampleRequest()
{
    return Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
        .ContinueWith(content =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(Timeout);
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Content = new StringContent(content.Result, Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain")
            };
        });
}
```

The sync version looks like this

```cs
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage SampleRequest()
{
    var content = Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    Thread.Sleep(Timeout);
    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK) 
    { 
        Content = new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain") 
    };
}
```

My client code to this test, looks like this (it is configured to time out after 30 seconds)

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRequests; i++)
{
    tasks.Add(new Task(() =>
    {
        MakeHttpPostRequest();
    }));
}
foreach (var task in tasks)
{
    task.Start();
}
```

I was not able to put it here in a nice way, but the table with the results are available at [github](https://gist.github.com/rmueller/0befdf9e40f795279f59)

The CPU, memory and disk IO is low. There's always at least 800 available threads (both worker and io threads)

```cs
public static void AvailableThreads()
{
    int workerThreads;
    int ioThreads;
    ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads(out workerThreads, out ioThreads);
    Console.WriteLine("Available threads {0} ioThreads {1}", workerThreads, ioThreads);
}
```

I've configured the DefaultConnectionLimit

```cs
System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = Int32.MaxValue;
```

My question is why there's a queue to answer those request?
In every test, I began with a response time almost exactly like the server Thread.Sleep() time, but the responses get slower as new request arrive.

Any tip on how I can discover where's the bootleneck?

It is a .net 4.0 solution, using self host option.

Edit: I've also tested with .net 4.5 and Web API 2.0, and got the same behaviour. 
First requests got the answer almost as soon as sleep expires, later it takes up to 4x the sleep time to get an answer.

Edit2: [Gist of the web api1 implementation](https://gist.github.com/rmueller/3e794488b963d0fa997e) and [gist of the web api2 implementation](https://gist.github.com/rmueller/aec0aef4150c8c1a1f8d)

Edit3: The MakeHttpPost method creates a new [WebApiClient](https://gist.github.com/rmueller/0a88c5675a9bd4476b8a)

Edit4:

If I change the

```
Thread.Sleep()
```

to

```
await Task.Delay(10000);
```

in the .net 4.5 version, it can handle all requests, as expected. So I don't think something related to any network issue. 
Since Thread.Sleep() blocks the thread and Task.Delay don't, looks like there's an issue with webapi to consume more threads? But there's available threads in the threadpool...

Edit 5: If I open 5 servers and double the number of clients, the server can respond to all requests. So looks like it's not a problem with number of request to a server, because I can 'scale' this solution running a lot of process in different ports. It's more a problem with the number of request to the same process.

Comment: What's in MakeHttpPostRequest?

Comment: Are you running the tests on the same machine that hosts the api, I think the problem is on your client side (tests). In your test you are starting several hundreds of tasks in parallel. This is creating a big load on the machine and the swapping of the threads is causing too much overhead. My suggestion is to try running your test with a Parallel.foreach. This will use a scheduler that schedules the threads based on the amount of cores and other parameters, and only uses the right amount of threads.

Comment: @alexm I've added the code.

Comment: @JimmyH I've also executed this test running all clients on my machine and the server on another machine. Also, I'm getting a situation that really looks like this in production, with 400+ clients and 2 servers.

Comment: Have you checked the real request time with a tool like fiddler?

Comment: @JimmyH I'll execute the test with less threads on multiple clientes and measure the time with fidller.

Comment: @JimmyH I've also tested with Task.Delay replacing the Thread.Sleep and then the problem is gone.

Comment: @Rafael, so when you use Task.Delay instead of Thread.Sleep the problem goes away. Then maybe the problem is a problem of too much blocked threads (same issue as i suggested on the client side). What if in your production code you make the controller action async and await the soap call (assuming you have an async version).

Comment: @JimmyH I'll try that and post the results here later.

Answer (score 2):

### How to Check the TCP/IP stack for overloading

Run Netstat on the server having the issue, look for any Time-Waits, Fin-Wait-1, Fin-Wait-2 and RST-Wait, RST-Wait2.  These are half-baked sessions whereby the stack is waiting for the other side to clean up.....OR.....the other side did send a packet in but the local machine could not process them yet depending on the Stacks' availability to do the job.

The kicker is that even sessions showing Established could be in trouble in that the time-out hasn't fired yet.

The symptoms described above are reminiscent of network or TCP/IP stack overload.  Very similar behavior is seen when routers get overloaded.

Comment: I've tested with Task.Delay and its works fine. So I think it's more related to web api than a tcp/ip overloading.

Comment: Just curious what did you see in Netstat any half-sessions?